# Unnest Json Array json_extract_scalar

Tags: arrays, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena, unnest

I have a table employee , column employee_detail which have data like:

```json
{'emp': 'myself', 'dept': 'IT', 'empid': '12345', 'empdetail': {'JoiningDetail': {'JoinedGeneratedTimestamp': 1683295496534, 'position': 12115}, 'xyz': None, 'abc': None}, 'title': 'SrDevelop'}
```

where I want to get JoinedGeneratedTimestamp and postition  data  while querying from athena

Below query I tried :

```sql
with data as(
   select employee_detail,
      json_extract_scalar((replace(employee_detail, '''', '"')),
     '$.empdetail.JoiningDetail.JoinedGeneratedTimestamp') as JoinedGeneratedTimestamp 
  from "employee" limit 5 )

select employee_detail, JoinedGeneratedTimestamp 
from data
```

Getting blank for JoinedGeneratedTimestamp field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure the "json" like field is in that format? also, maybe the JoinedGeneratedTimestamp sometimes holds non- scalar values?

the `json_exctract_scalar` can only extract boolean, number and string
if you wish to extract arrays, maps or structs (more complex types) use the regular `json_extract`

For both cases, based only on the data example you provided, it seems to work just fine

json_extract_scalar -

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{''emp'': ''myself'', ''dept'': ''IT'', ''empid'': ''12345'', ''empdetail'': {''JoiningDetail'': {''JoinedGeneratedTimestamp'': 1683295496534, ''position'': 12115}, ''xyz'': None, ''abc'': None}, ''title'': ''SrDevelop''}'
    AS employee_detail
)
select 
json_extract_scalar(replace(employee_detail, '''', '"'), '$.empdetail.JoiningDetail.JoinedGeneratedTimestamp') as join_generated_timestamp,
json_extract_scalar(replace(employee_detail, '''', '"'), '$.empdetail.JoiningDetail.position') as position
from dataset
```

output -

```
join_generated_timestamp, position
1683295496534, 12115
```

json_extract -

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT '{''emp'': ''myself'', ''dept'': ''IT'', ''empid'': ''12345'', ''empdetail'': {''JoiningDetail'': {''JoinedGeneratedTimestamp'': 1683295496534, ''position'': 12115}, ''xyz'': None, ''abc'': None}, ''title'': ''SrDevelop''}'
    AS employee_detail
)
select 
json_extract(replace(employee_detail, '''', '"'), '$.empdetail.JoiningDetail.JoinedGeneratedTimestamp') as join_generated_timestamp,
json_extract(replace(employee_detail, '''', '"'), '$.empdetail.JoiningDetail.position') as position
from dataset
```

output -

```
join_generated_timestamp, position
1683295496534, 12115
```